# How to disallow creation of object if related foreign key doesn't exists?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pytest, django-orm

Here is the setup

```py
class A(Model):
    pass

class B(Model):
    a = ForeignKey(A, on_delete=CASCADE)


assert A.objects.all().count() == 0
try:
    B.object.create(a_id=1)
except IntegrityError:
    print('error')
    # ... another logic to deal with situation
```

DB is PostgreSQL. There are no `A` objects yet (at least with `id=1`).

I try to create object `B` using the id of some hypothetical object `A` fetched from the 3rd party.

#### Expectation

If there is no object `A` -> IntegrityError is thrown -> deal with it (eg create object `A` with `id=1` and rerun).

#### Reality

Object `B` is created anyway despite having a foreign key constraint, IntegrityError (`Key (a_id)=(1) is not present in table "app_a"`) is thrown but is not fetched by try/except. Everything is messed up.

---

I don't what to `get_or_create` object `A` beforehand because I will end up with 2 queries every time I want to create `B` (and I need to create it many times while most of the time needed object `A` is already in DB)

---

## EDIT 1

As it turns out, the problem is with pytest. Only inside test I can't catch `IntegrityError`.

```
with pytest.raises(IntegrityError):
  b = B.objects.create(a_id=1)
```

Code above didn't raise `IntegrityError` despite the absence of `A` object with `id=1`. Nonetheless `IntegrityError`'s traceback is printed out in the console. And object `b` is created.

Comment: The `B` object is created, but not a `B` record. When you aim to insert it, it will error.

Comment: I just checked and id is already present on a newly created object `B` so it was inserted. And also I can fetch it from the database with `B.objects.get()`.

Comment: you did not `some_b.save()`, or use `B.objects.create(..)`, so you did not do anything at database side with the above logic.

Comment: oh, there is an error in question

Comment: You did not by any chance disabled the foreign key constraints, right?

Comment: I forgot `.object.create`, sorry

Comment: are you sure you imported the *correct* integrity error class (from `django.db.utils`)?

Comment: I'm using `from django.db import IntegrityError`, which is the same thing

Comment: I can not reproduce this locally: the exception is catched by the `except`. What Django version do you use?

Comment: `Django==2.2.1`, I will try to update it

Comment: Updated to the latest `2.2.3` but the error is still present.

Comment: hmm, I tried to simulate my example in django shell, and indeed everything worked just fine. But when I run the same code through pytest then these strange errors appear.

Comment: are you sure you did not overwrite the `IntegrityError`? Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: as I said the code works fine outside pytest, but when I test it the error appears.
Output of pytest: https://pastebin.com/2cfg169q . Without assert 0 the test will pass, but objects `A` will not be created (it should) because Integrity error is not caught.

Comment: the error seems to be `assert 0` which will *always* fail.

Comment: Even without it pytest will show me IntegrityError and passed test (1 ran, 1 passed, 1 error). The reason why I used `assert 0` is to simplify the rest of the code is that test (checking that `A` was created) which will only pollute output with additional errors. Here is output w/o assert and commented out code which was after it: https://pastebin.com/aC7yFZYC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with trying to catch `IntegrityError` inside an atomic transaction.

Guys from `pytest` [helped](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/754) to fix it `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)` instead of just `@pytest.mark.django_db`.